# How to write a cron expression that runs every 5 mins from 9:30 to 4:00 am on weekdays in spring/java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I have a `Spring Boot` application that has a `cron` expression for a job that I would like to run on weekdays MON-FRI between 9:30 am to 4:00 pm every 5 mins.

But looks like the `cron` expression is not correct.

**application.properties**

```
job.signal.cron=0 0/5 9:30-16 * * MON-FRI
```

**Error at startup:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'findSignal': For input string: "9:30" '9:30-16' in cron expression "0 0/5 9:30-16 * * MON-FRI"
        at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:511) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$null$1(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$2(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:444) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Came back with error: `Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 5 in "0/5 9:30-16 * * MON-FRI")`

Comment: Can you try this?  `0 0/5 9:30-16 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI`

Comment: 0 0/5 9:30-16 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI - Did not work. `Encountered invalid @Scheduled method for input string: "9:30" '9:30-16' in cron expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
0 30-55/5 9 * * MON-FRI
0 */5 10-15 * * MON-FRI
0 0 16 * * MON-FRI
```

Comment: You can't express `09:30`, so need write above `cron command`.

Comment: Thanks  bbuljj. Do all of the above represent the same thing ? Do you mind explaining `0 30-55/5 9 * * MON-FRI` as this one closely resembles the time and hours I am looking for.

Comment: And also how does this specify stopping the job @4:00 pm?

Comment: The above command are all different.
`0 30-55/5 9 * * MON-FRI` This command is every 5 minutes (from 09:30 through 09:55 Mon~Fri)
`0 */5 10-16 * * MON-FRI` This command is every 5 minutes (from 10:00 through 16:00 Mon~Fri)

Comment: Got it. Is there a way to merge both the commands into one or do I have to specify two cron expressions to fulfill my requirement ?

Comment: you have to express two cron.

Comment: `@Scheduled(cron = "${job.stock.buy-signal.cron1}")
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.stock.buy-signal.cron2}")`   Is this the correct way to represent both the cron expressions above a method ?

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "${job.stock.buy-signal.cron1}")
public void first(){}

@Scheduled(cron = "${job.stock.buy-signal.cron2}")
public void second(){}

Comment: Is there a way to merge both the cron expressions into one and make it call just one method? Because both of them currently call the same method but has to be separated out.

Comment: It is possible that two cron merge.
```@Scheduled(cron = "${job.stock.buy-signal.cron1}") @Scheduled(cron = "${job.stock.buy-signal.cron2}") public void cronTest() {} ```